# Setting RTC alarm

Tags: pi-pico, micropython

I'm somewhat confused by the use of [`rtc.irq`](https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/library/machine.RTC.html#machine.RTC.irq), more precisely the `trigger` argument. If I wanted to blink a LED every second using IRQ, the docs say that `trigger` has to be `RTC.ALARM0`. Do I have to use the same constant as `id` argument when creating the alarm with `rtc.alarm`?

In other words, `id` of `rtc.alarm` should be the same as `trigger` of `rtc.irq`? I guess I find it confusing that one time it's called `id` and the other time `trigger`?

And if I didn't want to use IRQ, the `id` of `rtc.alarm` can be any integer, correct?